# Rails string injection adds quotations marks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to enter a letter given by the get request into a Like statment in tails 3. So far I have the following code:

```
@entries = Entry.where("key LIKE '?%'", params[:letter]).order(:key)
```

Problem is it is creating the wrong kind of sql query adding quotation marks around the injected letter. it creates the following sql for :letter => 'a':

```
SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE (key LIKE ''a'%') ORDER BY key
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE (key LIKE 'a%') ORDER BY key
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@entries = Entry.where("key LIKE ?", "#{params[:letter]}%").order(:key)
```

Comment: Is that really the best option? it seems a little complicated, not very ruby like...

Comment: Why do you think this is complicated?

Comment: What I would think there would be, is a simple way to escape the quotation marks. instead you're telling me I need to move all of the phrase out into the variable, not very simple...

Comment: Is this even sql-injection safe?

Comment: @Nayish it is sql-injection safe, because it uses the `?`.

Comment: May be you should also downcase (if required) for key and params[:letter] for non mysql databases like Entry.where("LOWER(key) LIKE ?", "#{params[:letter].downcase}%")